# How to structure a taxomomy-like structure in a relational database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am working on a feature for categorizing things.  All items can have 0 or n children.

There will also be a need for 2 or more unrelated parents to have the same child..but maybe that won't be too necessary.

How do people create a schema for this?  Is it a matter of having this sort of table columns:

category_id | category_name | parent_id | child_id

Or is there some way of doing this that is more elegant and flexible?

Thanks!!

Comment: Martin answered how to tag items, but I am still not sure how to best create a higherarchy of the tags.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're speaking of tagging items, then you'd normally have an `articles` table, a `taxonomy_terms` table, and then a join table like `articles_taxonomy_terms`, which articles can have any number of related terms (tags).

Comment: Thanks Martin.  Just so I am more clear - could you explain how the columns would look like in each table? I think I am using different terminology so it is a bit confusing.

Comment: Sure. I've created a SQL schema gist here: https://gist.github.com/1330539. That should make sense if you're used to working with MySQL.

Comment: Also, a friend just tweeted the link to a tagging library. Check out https://github.com/freetag/freetag and see if that's of any help?